# C++ - Adding standalone callback that invokes a method in the calling class

Tags: c++, marshalling

I have a managed C++ object that makes a call to an unmanaged API with a function pointer.  Here is the setup:

**The *.h file:**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    void MyStandaloneCallback(void* obj) {
        EventArgs^ args = gcnew EventArgs();    
        ((MyClass*)obj)->OnReceived(args); 
    }

    void MyClass::OnReceived(EventArgs^ args) {
         ...
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the proper way to marshal  the pointer to my calling object (MyObject) on the callback that is defined (at top) outside the object. Making the object static is not an option.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: You can't pass a managed object (EventArgs^) to an unmanaged class.

Comment: Did I miss C++ adding managed objects? Might need to consider retagging....

Comment: The only thing unmanaged in my project is the API, not covered here. All the code you see here is managed code.

Comment: (The EventArgs is not the issue)

Comment: I used "EventArgs" as a catch-all. In this case "EventArgs" is my own class, again, not the issue.